# Spring Boot can't connect to MySQL container

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am having problems connecting to a MySQL server throught my Spring Boot application. I have a docker-compose file that unites a MySQL and PhpMyAdmin images, that runs perfectly fine on my local machine.

Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
 
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_secret_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app_db
      MYSQL_USER: db_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: db_user_pass
    ports:
      - "6033:3306"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
      
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

And here is my application.properties file:

[image]

I also tried using 'localhost' instead of 'db' and tried with both passwords but to no success.Here are my dependencies in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You're attempting to use `db` as a hostname in the connection string. That would only work if the Java application also runs via the same `docker-compose`. Seeing your docker-compose yaml, your connection string might need to be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:6033/app_db?useSSL=false`.

Comment: I tried using both 'db' and 'localhost' but nothing seemed to work

Comment: I think you should try to use `localhost` with port `6033` instead of `3306`, since according to your dockerfile, you're publishing port `3306` of the MySQL container to port `6033` on the host.

Comment: tried that as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the port to 6033 and the host to 'localhost' managed to change the error. In the end I was able to connect to the MySQL server with 'root' as a username:

[image]